# Addition table with hidden digits

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, alphametic

Similar to the [previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104185/sum-with-letters-find-the-values),
find the values behind the letters.

```
     T , E , M , A 
     K , A , K , A 
+    S , A , F , T 
-------------------
 F , E , S , T , A
```

These are roughly the Swedish words for *theme, cookie, soda*, and the result, *partying*.
All letters correspond to different digits, and leading digits in numbers are non-zero.

Below is a second puzzle of this type:

```
    A , N , A , N , A , S 
    M , A , T , O , S , T 
        T , O , M , A , T 
+           S , A , L , T 
-------------------------------
    S , A , L , L , A , D
```

The words are *pineapple, cheese, tomato, salt* with the total *salad*.

The solutions are unique.

Answer (score 1):

Human *un*friendly way to solve first puzzle.

> Let we call each carry digits c1 to c4.
> We have:
> [0]: 0 <= c1, c2, c3, c4 <= 2
> [1]: A+A+T=c1*10+A
> [2]: M+K+F+c1=T+c2*10
> [3]: E+A+A+c2=S+c3*10
> [4]: T+K+S+c3=E+c4*10; T<>0; K<>0; S<>0
> [5]: F=c4; F<>0
> ----
> [1] -> A+T=c1*10
> -> [6]: c1=1;
> -> [7]: A+T=10; A<>0; T<>0
> ---
> [4] + [3] -> T+K+(E+A+A+c2-c3*10)+c3=E+c4*10
> -> T+K+A+A+c2=c4*10+c3*9
> + [2] -> (M+K+F+1-c2*10)+K+A+A+c2=c4*10+c3*9
> -> [8]: M+K+K+A+A+1=(c4+c2+c3)*9
> [9]: 12 = 4+1+1+3+3 <= M+K+K+A+A <= 7+8+8+9+9 = 41
> + [8] -> 12 <= 9*(c2+c3+c4) <= 42
> -> [10]: 2<=c2+c3+c4<=4
> [4] + [6] + [2] -> (M+K+F+1-c2*10)+K+S+c3=E+c4*10
> + [5] -> [11]: M+K+K+S+1+c3+c4-E=(c2+c4)*10
> K<>F=c4; K<>0
> M+K+K+S+1+c3+c4-E<=7+8+9+9+1+2+2-0=38
> -> (c2+c4)*10<=37
> -> [12]: c2+c4<=3
> ----
> Consider c2=2;
> [2]: M+K+F+1=T+c2*10>=1+2*10=21
> -> M+K+F>=20
> -> M+K>=20-F
> + [0] -> M+K>=18
> M, K cannot both be 9 (impossible)
> -> [13]: c2<>2
> ----
> -> [8]: M+K+K+A+A+1=(c4+c2+c3)*9
> -> [7]: A+T=10; A<>0; T<>0
> [2]: M+K+F+1=T+c2*10
> [2] + [8] + [7] -> M+K=(10-A)+c2*10-1-c4=10+c2*10-A-1-c4
> -> M+K+K=9*c2+9*c3+9*c4-1-A-A
> -> [14]: A+K=9*c3+10*c4-c2-10
> -> [15]: 14<=9c3+10c4-c2<=27
> ----
> [2] + [3] + [4]
> -> (E+A+A+c2)+(T+K+S+c3)+(T+c2*10)=(M+K+F+c1)+(S+c3*10)+(E+c4*10)
> -> c2*11+20=M+F+1+c3*9+c4*10
> -> [16]: M=19+c2*11-c3*9-c4*11
> -> 10<=-c2*11+c3*9+c4*11<=19
> -> 10<=11*(c3+c4-c2)-2*c3<=19
> -> 10<=11*(c3+c4-c2)<=23
> -> c3+c4-c2=1 or (c3=2 and c2=c4=1)
> If (c3=2, c2=c4=1) -> M=1=F (impossible)
> -> c3+c4-c2=1
> ---
> [10] + [12] + [13] + [15] + [17]
> -> [17]: (c2, c3, c4) may be (1, 0, 2) or (1, 1, 1)
> -> [18]: c2+c3+c4=3
> -> [19]: c2=1
> -> [20]: c3+c4=2
> + [8]
> -> [21]: M+K+K+A+A=26
> [14] -> [22]: A+K=7+c4
> [16] -> [23]: M+F=12-c4
> [21] + [22]
> -> M=12-c4*2
> -> [24]: F=c4=2
> -> [25]: M=8
> -> [26]: c3=0
> -> [27]: A+K=9; K=T-1
> [3] -> [28]: E+A+A+1=S
> [27] + [7] + [28] + [25] + [24]:
> (A, T, K, E, S, M, F) = (4, 6, 5, 0, 9, 8, 2)

Answer (score 0):

From my previous answer, we can find the answers with brute force:

> ```
> from itertools import permutations
>
> for comb in permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], 7):
>     a, e, f, k, m, s, t = comb
>     if all([t, k, s, f]):
>         if int(f'{t}{e}{m}{a}') + int(f'{k}{a}{k}{a}') + int(f'{s}{a}{f}{t}') == int(f'{f}{e}{s}{t}{a}'):
>             print('a e f k m s t')
>             print(a, e, f, k, m, s, t)
> print('---------------')
> for comb in permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], 8):
>     a, d, l, m, n, o, s, t = comb
>     if all([t, k, s, f]):
>         if int(f'{a}{n}{a}{n}{a}{s}') + int(f'{m}{a}{t}{o}{s}{t}') + int(f'{t}{o}{m}{a}{t}') + int(f'{s}{a}{l}{t}') == int(f'{s}{a}{l}{l}{a}{d}'):
>             print('a d l m n o s t')
>             print(a, d, l, m, n, o, s, t)
> ```

Output:

> ```
> a e f k m s t
> 4 0 2 5 8 9 6
> ---------------
> a d l m n o s t
> 1 9 2 3 0 7 5 8
> ```

Comment: Thats more or less how I came up with them. Are there human-friendly steps to solve them?

Comment: I have done a sketch of how to do it but writing it all out would be incredibly tedious.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Yep. I'm sticking to my root, though.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting a Human friendly way to solve as requested by @Per Alexandersson.
Work in progress:
Puzzle 1:

> **F can only be 1 or 2** Reason: overflow digit of addition of 3 numbers.

considering @tsh suggestion

> **A + T = 10** Reason: A+A+T = A , so A+T should be 10 and the answer will be A+A+T = 1A (1 carried over).

Which implies:

> 1. A, T cannot be 0 , since if A = 0 , T = 10 vice versa.
>  2. A, T cannot be 5. Since A+T = 10 , A = 5 then T = 5. But A,T are different numbers(i hope).

Comment: "A and T are either both odd or both even" -> Why not just A+T=10.

Comment: @tsh Oh i realise you are right, A+T = 10 and neither A nor T can be 5. Does that sound better ?!